# Get the BeforeProperties and AfterProperties in ItemCheckedIn

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, event-receivers

I am currently trying to develop an event receiver that uses properties.AfterProperties object in updating and ItemUpdated and ItemUpdating event, so can I get the BeforeProperties and AfterProperties in my ItemCheckedIn event  or ItemCheckedout event?
If I explain my scenario,when the user upload a document he will select a drop down,public and confidential,and when confidential is selected am triggering a custom action such that,3 people pickers were populated for entering the user names for giving access programmatically.                                I can say its a kind of approval workflow i am trying to implement through visual web part and event receiver -without using `SP D 2013` / `WF Manager`.
The strange thing is that, it works in my test and staging environment, but fails in production.

```
 public override void ItemUpdating(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        base.ItemUpdating(properties);

        try
        {
            if (properties.AfterProperties["vti_sourcecontrolcheckedoutby"] == null
            && properties.BeforeProperties["vti_sourcecontrolcheckedoutby"] != null)
            {
                if (IsConfidential(properties))
                {
                    SetRoleChanged(properties);
                }
            }
    }
  public void SetRoleChanged(SPItemEventProperties properties)
    {
        try
        {
            string currentRead = 
        Convert.ToString(properties.AfterProperties[READACCESSCOL]);
            string oldRead = 
        Convert.ToString(properties.BeforeProperties[READACCESSCOL]);
            string x2 = 
        Convert.ToString(properties.ListItem[READACCESSCOL]);
        } 
       string currentView = 
        Convert.ToString(properties.AfterProperties[VIEWACCESSCOL]);
         string oldView = 
         Convert.ToString(properties.BeforeProperties[VIEWACCESSCOL]);
            if (currentView != oldView)
            {

                properties.AfterProperties["ViewChanged"] = "true";   
            }

      public override void ItemUpdated(SPItemEventProperties properties)
       {
        base.ItemUpdated(properties);
       }
```

Comment: Why are you not using `ItemUpdated` instead of `ItemUpdating`?

Comment: Did not use `ItemUpdated`.Will I get the values if I use `ItemUpdated` event?

Comment: Yes. Please use ItemUpdated

Comment: The weird thing is that, it works in my test and staging.But it fails in Production.So if the issue is in `ItemUpdating`, then my doubt is that, the issue should  appear in the test and staging environments. We have tested thoroughly this in the above 2 environments and ported the content db back up to production and deployed the webpart's latest  wsp. So as per my understanding there should not be an issue when triggering the event receiver.The only  difference between in  staging and production is, staging is <http://mydms.company.com> and production is in <https://mydms.company.com> .

Answer (score 0):

Below is the list of supported Events for `SPListItem`

- `ItemAdding`
- `ItemAdded`
- `ItemDeleting`
- `ItemDeleted`
- `ItemUpdating`
- `ItemUpdated`
- `ItemFileConverted`
- `ItemFileMoving`
- `ItemFileMoved`
- `ItemCheckingIn`
- `ItemCheckedIn`
- `ItemCheckingOut`
- `ItemCheckedOut`
- `ItemAttachmentAdding`
- `ItemAttachmentAdded`
- `ItemAttachmentDeleting`
- `ItemAttachmentDeleted`

You can use `SPItemEventProperties properties` to get hold of `BeforeProperties` and `AfterProperties`

Comment: Thank you for the  reply. I am trying to get the value for two operations.One is when the user uploads the new document into the document library.My event receiver triggers correctly and I am able to get the values of 3  people picker values. in my scenario  read_access,view_access, ContributeNoDel_Access people picker values.Now i am triggering one method and  doing some manipulations.After this,when the same  user or other user is trying to edit the same document he checked out and edit properties , i mean he edits the these 3 people picker values and save and checkedin.

Comment: You should handle event `ItemCheckedIn` and read those inside that method.

Comment: When the user CheckedIn after editing the properties,I mean, Editing the docmuent who has the necessary privileges, ItemUpdated event triggers and am saving 3 values and I need these values available  in ItemcheckedIn method.Is this possible?

Comment: I have tried to access those values but those were, I am unable to get those saved values in ItemUpdated method in ItemCheckedIn method.

Comment: Update question and post relevant code.